# Service is running in multiple instance

Tags: android, service, android-sensors

I have a created a background service which will work even if the application is killed. In the service I am getting the data from the sensor. But it seems that my service is returning sensors value multiple times in a second resulting of which is my application is getting hanged.

Here is my service:

```
public class StepCounterService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    public static Boolean FLAG = false;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private StepDetector detector;

    private PowerManager mPowerManager;
    private WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       /* mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(detector,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);*/

        Log.d("zzz", "start command");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        new StepCountManager(this);
        Log.d("zzz", "create");

        FLAG = true;

        Log.e("Service_Started", "");
        detector = new StepDetector(this);


        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(detector,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);


        mPowerManager = (PowerManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "S");
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        reloadSettings();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        FLAG = false;
        if (detector != null) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(detector);
        }

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }

        Log.e("Service_destroyed", "");
    }

    public void reloadSettings() {

        if (detector != null) {
            detector.setSensitivity(
                    Float.valueOf("10")
            );
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        //Restart the service once it has been killed android


//        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +100, restartServicePI);

        ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE))
                .set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent
                        .getService(this, 3, new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class), 0));

    }

}
```

Here is my class implementing sensorEventListener:

```
public class StepDetector implements SensorEventListener {


    public static UpdateStepCount mStepsUpdater;


    public static int CURRENT_SETP = 0;

    public static float SENSITIVITY = 0;   //SENSITIVITY

    private float mLastValues[] = new float[3 * 2];
    private float mScale[] = new float[2];
    private float mYOffset;
    private static long end = 0;
    private static long start = 0;
    private float   mLimit = 10;


    private float mLastDirections[] = new float[3 * 2];
    private float mLastExtremes[][] = { new float[3 * 2], new float[3 * 2] };
    private float mLastDiff[] = new float[3 * 2];
    private int mLastMatch = -1;


    public StepDetector(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        int h = 480;
        mYOffset = h * 0.5f;
        mScale[0] = -(h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2)));
        mScale[1] = -(h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX)));

    }
    public void setSensitivity(float sensitivity) {
        mLimit = sensitivity; // 1.97  2.96  4.44  6.66  10.00  15.00  22.50  33.75  50.62
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
         Log.d("zzz", "Sensor changed");
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        // Log.i(Constant.STEP_DETECTOR, "onSensorChanged");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            } else {
                int j = (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) ? 1 : 0;
                if (j == 1) {
                    float vSum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        final float v = mYOffset + event.values[i] * mScale[j];
                        vSum += v;
                    }
                    int k = 0;
                    float v = vSum / 3;

                    float direction = (v > mLastValues[k] ? 1: (v < mLastValues[k] ? -1 : 0));
                    if (direction == -mLastDirections[k]) {
                        // Direction changed
                        int extType = (direction > 0 ? 0 : 1); // minimum or
                        // maximum?
                        mLastExtremes[extType][k] = mLastValues[k];
                        float diff = Math.abs(mLastExtremes[extType][k]- mLastExtremes[1 - extType][k]);

                        if (diff > mLimit) {
                            boolean isAlmostAsLargeAsPrevious = diff > (mLastDiff[k] * 2 / 3);
                            boolean isPreviousLargeEnough = mLastDiff[k] > (diff / 3);
                            boolean isNotContra = (mLastMatch != 1 - extType);

                            if (isAlmostAsLargeAsPrevious && isPreviousLargeEnough && isNotContra) {
                                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                if (end - start > 500) {
                                    Log.i("Step_Detector", "CURRENT_SETP:"
                                            + CURRENT_SETP);
                                    CURRENT_SETP++;
                                    mLastMatch = extType;
                                    start = end;
                                }
                            } else {
                                mLastMatch = -1;
                            }
                        }
                        mLastDiff[k] = diff;
                    }
                    mLastDirections[k] = direction;
                    mLastValues[k] = v;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("sensorSteps", String.valueOf(CURRENT_SETP));
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(mStepsUpdater!=null){
                    mStepsUpdater.UpdateStepCount(CURRENT_SETP);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);


    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

I want my service to return sensor data once in second, so that I can store that data in db. Can someone tell me how I can get sensor data every second instead of multiples time in a second.

Comment: You are asking for `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`. If you do not want them that fast, use a different value. However, AFAIK, there is nothing that will go as low as one per second.

Comment: @CommonsWare I changed SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST to SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_Normal. Its working fine but after killing the application the sensor data is again resetting to 0 why?\

Comment: Most likely, your process is being terminated. This is perfectly normal. Using a foreground service may help with that.